# How do I print reverse of the intersection of 2 arrays of different lengths?

Tags: c++17

I am trying to output the reverse of the intersection of two arrays of different length. I can so far print the intersection, but not in inverse order. I already have some code so far. How do I modify this to be able to print the intersection between the 2 arrays in reverse order? The arrays in question are not sorted.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int n1,n2,i,j;
cin>>n1>>n2;
int arr2[n2];
int arr1[n1];
stack <int> s;
for(i=0;i<n1;i++){
   cin>>arr1[i];
}
for(i=0;i<n2;i++){
   cin>>arr2[i];
}
for(i=0;i<n1;i++){
   for(j=0;j<n2;j++){
  if(arr1[i]==arr2[j]){
        s.push(arr1[i]);
        cout<<s.top()<<endl;
  }
}
}
}
```

Sample input:
6 4
1 2 3 4 5 6
2 6 4 1

Sample output:
1
2
4
6

Comment: 1) Are the arrays sorted? If yes, then you can do it in `m+n`.

Comment: Nope they aren't.

Comment: Please add some test cases as input and expected outputs. Say, what should the output be when `int arr1  = {1,2,3,4,5,6}` and `int arr2  = {2,6,4,1}`.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is incorrect in that expressions like

```
int arr2[n2];
```

are erroneous and work only because of compiler extensions to the standard. Use `std::vector` instead of plain arrays if you don't know array length. Also, don't underestimate the importance of source code indendation.

Now to the main point. The proper way of achieving your goal is this:

- copy the arrays to `std::vector`s (or just sort them, if you don't care if they are sorted),
- sort these vectors,
- apply `std::set_intersection` from `<algorithm>` standard library to these sorted vectors,
- print out the contents of the resulting vector in reversed order.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection for an example of code that uses `std::set_intersection`.